# Java Reflection : making a subclass instance be referred to as if it was super instance

Tags: java, reflection

consider the following:

```
public class A {
    public String name = "i am a A instance";
}
public class B extends A {
    public String name = "i am a B instance";
}

public class ReflectTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ainstance = new A();
        A binstance = new B();
        B bbinstance = new B();
        System.out.println(bbinstance.name);
        System.out.println(ainstance.getClass().cast(binstance).name);
        System.out.println(ainstance.getClass().cast(bbinstance).name);
        System.out.println(ainstance.getClass().cast(binstance).getClass());
        System.out.println(ainstance.getClass().cast(bbinstance).getClass());
    }

}
```

the output is:

```
i am a B instance
i am a A instance
i am a A instance
class cs236703.s2013.hw4.tests.B
class cs236703.s2013.hw4.tests.B
```

Is there a way to manipulate java reflections to return class A instead of class B in the last 2 printlns?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not happy with polymorphism ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to manipulate java reflections to return class A instead of class B in the last 2 printlns?

No there isn't.

The `getClass()` method returns the *actual* class of the target method, no matter what you've cast the object's reference to.  You can't change this, either using simple Java or using reflection.

<sup>(It is theoretically possible to do some behind-the-scenes nastiness in a native library that interferes with an object's type.  But this would be non-portable, **horribly unsafe** and not something that a sane programmer should ever contemplate doing ...)</sup>